# I want to run a command every 10 minutes in crontab on a certain directory

Tags: linux, cron, ubuntu-18.04, find

Running a server with Ubuntu 18.04

I am attempting to run this command every 10 minutes in crontab on the directory /var/www/html:

```
  find . -type f -name "*.maintenance" -delete
```

Is this the correct syntax to accomplish this?

```
  */10 * * * * /var/www/html find . -type f -name "*.maintenance" -delete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
*/10 * * * * find /var/www/html -type f -name "*.maintenance" -delete
```

In the future, you can try creating the cronjob and checking the logs if it doesn't work.